# How can I add / upload bulk entries to Excel 2010 Autocorrect?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I currently have about 200 entries of autocorrect but it's painful to add one by one manually to "autocorrect" (File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options > AutoCorrect tab). These entries are phrases for long piece of text  e.g. ROI = Return Of Investment etc.

Is there any way to upload these entries quickly ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add them to the `.acl` file as explained in [this KB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956104.aspx).

> To use your AutoCorrect entries on another computer (or to share them
>   with another user profile on your computer), locate the .acl files in
>   the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Office` folder. (You can type the path in
>   Windows Explorer exactly as shown here and the %AppData% environment
>   variable will automatically expand to the full path. In Windows 7,
>   that path is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office` by
>   default, but it might be different on your computer.)

Note, this may interfere with your other template settings -

> You cannot extract and copy only the AutoCorrect entries. And if you
>   copy and paste the entire file, you will replace the styles and other
>   items in the template file that you overwrite.

In other words, this is possible, but not easily done.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick answer. Sorry for my misleading description. I don't have the .acl file in computer1 yet. I need to create this .acl file from an excel spreadsheet. Is there any quick way to move the data from the .xls file to .acl file?

Comment: It looks like you accidentally created a second user ID.  This will interfere with editing your own posts, commenting within your thread, accepting an answer and accumulating rep.  See http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts to get your accounts merged, which will fix that.  The Site's Q&A format relies on answers being solutions to the question, so posting something like this, which should be a comment on Raystafarian's answer, will attract downvotes and likely get deleted.

Comment: @MelvinChoi You will need an existing .acl file to edit, so I'd say just use the one that already exists by default. Transferring plaintext will require some finagling.

Answer (score 2):

*If* you're open to VBA, there's the `Application.AutoCorrect` object that has `.AddReplacement` method [KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196318.aspx).

You could do something like this -

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")

With Application.AutoCorrect
    For Each c In rng
        .AddReplacement c, c.Offset(, 1)
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

That's assuming you list is in A1:B100 where column A should be replaced with column B.